# Assign a existing jira ticket/issue to a user in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I'm trying to assign a existing jira ticket using python. Tried the below methods , but none are working. I'm able to add comments but not assign the issue

```
    #Method 1 Using Jira library - Getting JiraError HTTP None, text list index out of range
    from jira import JIRA
    jira_connection = JIRA(basic_auth=(username,password),server)
    issue = jira_connection.issue('100')
    jira_connection.assign_issue(issue,user_name)

    #Tried below way as well 
    issue.update(assignee={'accountId':'natash5'})


    #Method 2 Using Servicedesk - the update_issue_field function was empty in the source code
    from atlassian import ServiceDesk
    sd = ServiceDesk(url= "")
    sd.update_issue_field('100',{'assignee':'user_name')

    #Method 3 Soap API - SAXParse exception invalid token
    from suds import Client
    cl = Client(url)
    auth = cl.service.login(username,password)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

url = "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/assignee"

auth = HTTPBasicAuth("email@example.com", "<api_token>")

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

payload = json.dumps( {
    "accountId": "5b10ac8d82e05b22cc7d4ef5"
} )

response = requests.request(
    "PUT",
    url,
    data=payload,
    headers=headers,
    auth=auth
)

print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
```

I've run into the same issue, use the endpoints yourself rather than the - https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueidorkey-assignee-put
If you're interested I'm putting together a repo that has a lot of this stuff in it with ways to get stuff done. There is still a lot to tidy up in it so conceder this a beta release :) https://github.com/dren79/JiraScripting_public

Answer (score 0):

```
import psutil
import socket
from datetime import datetime

def get_running_processes(name=None):
    process_list = []  # Use a list to store processes
    hostname = socket.gethostname()  # Get the hostname of the machine
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # Get current datetime as a string

    for process in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name', 'username']):
        try:
            process_info = process.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'username'])
            if name is None or process_info['name'] == name:
                process_info['hostname'] = hostname
                process_info['timestamp'] = current_time
                process_info['status'] = 'Not Available' if process_info['name'] == 'notepad.exe' else 'Available'
                process_list.append(process_info)
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            pass

    return process_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes_list = get_running_processes(name="notepad.exe")
    print(processes_list)
```